# PowerShell: Display the differences in permissions between folders and their parents

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions

I'm hoping to come up with a script that can walk a directory tree on a Windows server and show me a tree that only includes directories whose permissions are different from it's parent (or sub) directory.  I want to produce an easily understandable report that can help me quickly audit the permissions of a folder structure.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
DIR "Z:\FileShare" -directory -recurse | GET-ACL | where {$_.AreAccessRulesProtected -eq $true} | select path, accessToString | format-list  |out-file c:\permissions.txt
```

This produces a usable set of data as is but it's a bit bulky.

What I don't know is how to have it filter out redundant text, namely lines like "BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl" and instead only show me the delta.  Human readable psudo-code might be "if this ACL line can be found in the immediate parent directory, don't show it here."

Comment: What I was trying to say is that a `FileSecurity` and a `DirectorySecurity` object have many different properties and comparing all of them against the parent ACL could be quite complex. By the looks of it, you're only wanting to compare 3 properties (`FileSystemRights` // `AccessControlType` // `IdentityReference`), if that's the case it is doable and not so hard to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this with a few folders setting up different ACLs with my own user and it seem to be working but I haven't tested enough to be sure. Basically, the script will loop through directories and add the ACLs to a dictionary where the **Keys** are each `IdentityReference` and the **Values** are the properties from the ACLs which you're interested on (`FileSystemRights` and `AccessControlType`) in addition to the folder's absolute path. While enumerating the directories, each object will be compared against the stored values using the `Compare-Acl` function which only returns `$true` if the object is different.

```sh
using namespace System.Collections
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

$map = [Dictionary[string, ArrayList]]::new()

$outObj = {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        AbsolutePath      = $dir.FullName
        FileSystemRights  = $acl.FileSystemRights
        IdentityReference = $acl.IdentityReference
        AccessControlType = $acl.AccessControlType
    }
}

function Compare-Acl {
param(
    [object[]]$Reference,
    [object]$Difference
)
    foreach($ref in $Reference)
    {
        $fsRights = $ref.FileSystemRights -eq $Difference.FileSystemRights
        $actRef = $ref.AccessControlType -eq $Difference.AccessControlType
        if($fsRights -and $actRef)
        {
            return $false
        }
    }
    $true
}

foreach($dir in Get-ChildItem Z:\FileShare -Directory -Recurse)
{
    foreach($acl in (Get-Acl $dir.FullName | Where-Object AreAccessRulesProtected).Access)
    {
        if($thisKey = $map[$acl.IdentityReference])
        {
            $obj = & $outObj
            if(Compare-Acl -Reference $thisKey -Difference $obj)
            {
                $null = $thisKey.Add($obj)
            }
            continue
        }
        $obj = & $outObj
        $null = $map.Add($acl.IdentityReference, [object[]]$obj)
    }
}

$map.Keys.ForEach({ $map[$_] })| Export-Csv path\to\acls.csv -NoTypeInformation
```